# Connect to SQL Server and retrieve Db name and size with PowerShell code

Tags: sql, powershell

It's needed to connect to SQL server from PowerShell code and get each DB which is restored and their size.

```
$SqlServer = "localhost\SQL2019";

$SqlLogin = "user1";

$SqlPassw = "user1"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SqlServer; User ID=$SqlLogin; Password=$SqlPassw;"

$SqlConnection.Open()

$SqlCmd = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()

$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT name

FROM    sys.databases"

$objReader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

while ($objReader.read()) {
    Write-Output $objReader.GetValue(0)
}
$objReader.close()
```

And this actual script showing all the db's name that are restored on this SQL server.

Another script which can show the Database size is:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(SUM(
        CAST( (size * 8.0/1024) AS DECIMAL(15,2) )
    ) AS VARCHAR(20)),' MB') AS [database_size]
FROM sys.database_files;
```

I actually tried to make an array from values I got in the previous script and go through this array like this to get the size of each db:

```
$SqlServer = "localhost\SQL2019";

$SqlLogin = "user1";

$SqlPassw = "user1"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SqlServer; User ID=$SqlLogin; Password=$SqlPassw;"

$SqlConnection.Open()

$SqlCmd = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()

$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT name

FROM    sys.databases"

$objReader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

while ($objReader.read()) {
    foreach($dbs in $objReader.GetValue(0)){

        $dbsArr = @($dbs)

        $objReader.close()

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $dbsArr.Count; $i++) {

            $SqlCmd1 = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()

            $SqlCmd1.CommandText = "use $dbsArr[$i]

            SELECT
                CONCAT(CAST(SUM(
                    CAST( (size * 8.0/1024) AS DECIMAL(15,2) )
                ) AS VARCHAR(20)),' MB') AS [database_size]

            FROM sys.database_files;"

            $objReader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

            while ($objReader.read()) {
                Write-Output $objReader.GetValue(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
$objReader.close()
```

But it doesn't work for me!

Please advice how to get DB name and size probably in 1 iteration(1 query). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with DBATOOLS module

```
Install-Module dbatools -Scope CurrentUser #only once

Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $Sql|select Name, SizeMB
```